# Unable to mount my Nexus 4 as USB mass storage on Xubuntu 16.04 via MTP or otherwise

Tags: android, mtp

This seems to be a basic concern. One one hand I have this Nexus 4 smartphone, on the other hand my Xubuntu 16.04 workstation, and in beetween a USB cable.

I want to transfert files from the phone to the PC and possibly the otherway around too.

I seem to remember that I did that maybe one or two years ago, without memorable hurdles.

Now I'm stuck.

MTP is activated on the phone. On the computer, `libmtp version: 1.1.10`, updated a few minutes ago. Indeed the whole system is as up-to-date as APT can do.

What seems to be the first troubleshooting step, `mtp-detect`, fails : 
`No raw devices found`

I have reviewed quite a few "howtos" and other materials on the web, none of which seem to be really recent, and I haven't found any indication that something may have changed recently.

I am down to suspecting the cable. It charges the battery all right but I read here or there that there *may* be USM cables that although enabling charging are unfit for file transfer. Could that be ? How could I check that ?

Also, while there is indeed plenty of material floating around, they all seem to be half-backed "quick fix", but I haven't been able to find any comprehensive resource. Yet those must exist, but where ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Well, I recommend to upgrade you Linux Kernal to Kernal 4.6.4 and install adb tools.

Ugrading kernal can be found in this blog [Click here](http://www.ubuntumaniac.com/2016/07/how-to-updateupgrade-to-linux-kernel.html).
Install Adb tools as follows :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot
sudo reboot
```

The above steps should solve your problem.

Comment: "could possibly solve your probelm" Answer with confidence. Answers should fix issues, even if you are wrong you can update later :)

Comment: I'd rather not update the _kernel_ outside the normal update process of the distro.

Comment: How would ADB help ? I do not plan to do any Android dev any time soon, and if I did, I would start by making sure that the most basic connection is operational.